# Rails Form Builder - How to place html attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a server_form iteration where I put `class: 'form-control'`
It works fine, except of the last iteration with `|spec_fields|`

```
= form_for @server do |server_form|
  = server_form.label :hostname
  = server_form.text_field :hostname, class: 'form-control'

  = server_form.label :description
  = server_form.text_field :description, class: 'form-control'

  = server_form.fields_for :spec do |spec_fields|
    Count of CPUs  : #{spec_fields.text_field :cpucount}
    RAM (GB): #{spec_fields.text_field :ram_gb}
    HD (GB): #{spec_fields.text_field :hd_gb}
    HD used (GB): #{spec_fields.text_field :hdused_gb}
```

My Question is: How can I put the `form-control` class also into `|spec_fields|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do it outside the `fields_for` block:

```
= form_for @server do |server_form|
  = server_form.label      :hostname
  = server_form.text_field :hostname,    class: 'form-control'
  = server_form.label      :description
  = server_form.text_field :description, class: 'form-control'

  = server_form.fields_for :spec do |spec_fields|
    Count of CPUs  : #{ spec_fields.text_field :cpucount,  class: 'form-control' }
    RAM (GB):        #{ spec_fields.text_field :ram_gb,    class: 'form-control' }
    HD (GB):         #{ spec_fields.text_field :hd_gb,     class: 'form-control' }
    HD used (GB):    #{ spec_fields.text_field :hdused_gb, class: 'form-control' }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) you'd have to pass it in before the block so...

```
= server_form.fields_for :spec, class: 'form-control' do |spec_fields|
    Count of CPUs  : #{spec_fields.text_field :cpucount}
    RAM (GB): #{spec_fields.text_field :ram_gb}
    HD (GB): #{spec_fields.text_field :hd_gb}
    HD used (GB): #{spec_fields.text_field :hdused_gb}
```

should work